# RROR – unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly and results may not be recorded. Please contact technical support

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2, adobe-captivate, sap-successfactors

We are in the process of implementing SuccessFactors LMS, and trying to play and view SCORM compatible files exported from Adobe Captivate 8 and 9 in Success Factors LMS.

I get the message - 'ERROR – unable to acquire LMS API, content may not play properly and results may not be recorded. Please contact technical support’

I have tried SCORM versions 1.2 v3 and 2004 V2 and V4.  We can view the content, however it does not track, show as complete etc.

We are also producing Scorm compliant files using Skillcast and Articulate, but we still hit the same issue, we can view the content after closing the API error window, but still does not track.

Anyone experienced this problem before? Or know of a fix?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally this issue comes up when the course is unable to get the SCORM API from the LMS...I have seen a ton of SCORM content running in Success Factors before, so I wonder if the issue is in the setup.  Are you seeing any "Access Denied" type errors in the browser element inspector/developer tools?  I wonder if the course just can not find/have access to the player window.  If the course is launching in a new window, you may want to try launching it in the frameset.  I have seen folks get around this issue by making sure the player and sco are in the same window...

If you wanted to rule out the content being the issue, you can always test your content in the SCORM Cloud's free sandbox (https://cloud.scorm.com) to make sure the course is properly asking for the API...

If you have any other questions, we would be happy to help...you can just shoot us an email at support@scorm.com.

Thank you!

Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, I tried to reproduce the scorm material and this time I used articulate, and I unticked the box that say open in a new window. But I Still get the same API error message

Comment: Interesting...out of curiosity, can you give your course a test in SCORM Cloud to see if it launches there?  If it does, I wonder if the issue is the Success Factors setup...meaning the wherever the course is being imported to, can not find the SCORM API on launch...if the course does launch in SCORM Cloud, then at least, we know the course is set up correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the content is not speaking to the Learning Management System (LMS).  The code that runs to initialize the session doesn't happen. There is no return "ping" from the LMS.

You will get this error when you publish in SCORM and run from your desktop, or from a web server that isn't connected to an LMS.  If it occurs when you are launching from an LMS it can either mean that the SCORM API isn't configured correctly, or your content server is on a different domain (cross-domain) than your application servers.

To test, you should try launching your content in different browsers.  Our system was configured in such a way that Firefox and Chrome read our content to be cross-domain issue, and threw the SCORM API error, but Internet Explorer worked just fine.

In the end, it was determined that our server configuration in tandem with our firewall and security settings read the Content server as cross-domain and we had to redeploy our content servers within the firewall.